# Oracle SQL full outer join invalid identifier

Tags: oracle

I am getting an invalid identifier error in my full outer join clause. I think it may have to do with my select statement but not sure where.
Here is the query below:

```
select  h.laborlev2nm "Labor Acct", h.laborlev2dsc "Dept Name",
    to_char(b.pay_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as "PDate", 
    to_char(d.start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as "SDate", 
    to_char(d.end_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as "EDate",
    c.personnum "ID", c.fullnm "FullName",
    d.pay_type "Pay Type", f.name "Paycode", f.paycode_id "Paycode ID", 
    j.dags_objectcode "DAGS", NULL AS "Raw Hours", 


'Regular' AS "Retro Paycode Name",
101 AS "Retro Paycode ID", 0 AS "Computed Hours", 0 AS "Retro Hours", 

CASE 
    WHEN f.name = 'CH to Salaried Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'Change in BU Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'FTE Change Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'LOA Overpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'LOA Underpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'New Hire Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'Overpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'Retro Adjustment' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'Salaried to CH Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'Termination Pay Adj' THEN li.amount
    WHEN f.name = 'Underpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount
    ELSE NULL
END AS "Retro Dollars",


b.gross_pay "Gross", c.ftepct "FTE", 'Regular' "Reg/Cas",  bu.external_key "BU",  
d.pay_adjustment_id "Pay Adj ID", d.hourly_rate "H Rate", d.pay_type "P type"
--jc.jobtitledsc "Job Title"

from 
TKCSOWNER.KSS_EMP_JOB_INFO a , TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYROLL b,  TKCSOWNER.PERSON c, 
TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYROLL_DETAIL d, TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYCODE_MAP f, TKCSOWNER.KSS_BARGAINING_UNIT BU,
TKCSOWNER.LABORACCT h, TKCSOWNER.KSS_DAGSPAY_OBJCD_MAP j

full outer join TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAY_ADJ_LINE_ITEM li on (d.pay_adjustment_id = li.pay_adjustment_id)
```

The error is stating that my d.pay_adjustment_id is an invalid identifier on this last line of code.

Thank you in advanced for any advice

Comment: desc TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYROLL_DETAIL;

Comment: btw, how come you are not joining the rest of the tables, a-j ?

Comment: Since this is an Oracle question, why did you add the tags for MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: NEVER mix old-fashioned comma separated list with ansi join syntax, that is a recipe for nightmares

Comment: So TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYROLL_DETAIL is a table that shows an employees pay amount and has an identifier that indicates an adjustment to the pay. This identifier links to another table that shows the adjustment using the pay_adjustment_id.

Comment: Are all those tables separated by commas meant to be a vast Cartesian product?

Comment: I'm only using a join for these tables, but I do have a where statement that limits the select statement, but the main issue is coming from the full outer join

Comment: No it's not a vast cartesian product of all the tables, just the two im joining

Comment: @Used_By_Already What syntax should i use for the comma's?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` instead of each comma; then the reader knows the Cartesian product was intended (and not some silly oversight).

Comment: What if more than 1 table has a cross join, do i define twice EX:     T1 cross join T2,  T1 cross join T3

Comment: yes, as stated, EACH comma

Comment: `No it's not a vast Cartesian product of all the tables, just the two im joining` but it IS a vast Cartesian product UNLESS you add some joining logic. **Do you have a where clause you have not included?**

Comment: @Used_By_Already, Thanks, The cross join fixed the error and it is working now. You are the greatest, how do i give you cred or points.

Comment: Thanks! all the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tables are separated by a comma and **nothing else is included through the where clause to limit the effect** you are creating a CROSS JOIN. So for each comma there is a CROSS JOIN.

This is how I understand your query, which involves a multi-table Cartesian product:

```
SELECT h.laborlev2nm "Labor Acct"
       , h.laborlev2dsc "Dept Name"
       , to_char(b.pay_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "PDate"
       , to_char(d.start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "SDate"
       , to_char(d.end_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "EDate"
       , c.personnum "ID"
       , c.fullnm "FullName"
       , d.pay_type "Pay Type"
       , f.NAME "Paycode"
       , f.paycode_id "Paycode ID"
       , j.dags_objectcode "DAGS"
       , NULL AS "Raw Hours"
       , 'Regular' AS "Retro Paycode Name"
       , 101 AS "Retro Paycode ID"
       , 0 AS "Computed Hours"
       , 0 AS "Retro Hours"
       , CASE WHEN f.NAME = 'CH to Salaried Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'Change in BU Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'FTE Change Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'LOA Overpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'LOA Underpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'New Hire Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'Overpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'Retro Adjustment' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'Salaried to CH Reg Pay Adj' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'Termination Pay Adj' THEN li.amount WHEN f.NAME = 'Underpayment Adjustment' THEN li.amount ELSE NULL END AS "Retro Dollars"
       , b.gross_pay "Gross"
       , c.ftepct "FTE"
       , 'Regular' "Reg/Cas"
       , bu.external_key "BU"
       , d.pay_adjustment_id "Pay Adj ID"
       , d.hourly_rate "H Rate"
       , d.pay_type "P type"
      --jc.jobtitledsc "Job Title"
FROM TKCSOWNER.KSS_EMP_JOB_INFO a
CROSS JOIN TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYROLL b
CROSS JOIN TKCSOWNER.PERSON c
CROSS JOIN TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYROLL_DETAIL d
CROSS JOIN TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAYCODE_MAP f
CROSS JOIN TKCSOWNER.KSS_BARGAINING_UNIT BU
CROSS JOIN TKCSOWNER.LABORACCT h
CROSS JOIN TKCSOWNER.KSS_DAGSPAY_OBJCD_MAP j
FULL JOIN TKCSOWNER.KSS_PAY_ADJ_LINE_ITEM li ON (d.pay_adjustment_id = li.pay_adjustment_id)
```

Comment: Thank a bunch!! you are correct about the multi table cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in Comments and in the accepted Answer, you should never mix Oracle "comma syntax" and SQL Standard (ANSI) syntax for joins in the same query. It is not illegal, but the syntax rules are so complicated it is not likely you will get them right - and, besides, there is no reason to do it.

To your specific question:

The error has nothing to do with the last join being an *outer* join. You would get the same error if you change it to an *inner* join. Rather: when you mix Oracle syntax and ANSI syntax, the join using ANSI syntax is done first, as if enclosed in parentheses. You are full-outer-joining (or, really ANSI joining) the tables aliased `j` and `li`. At that point, only the names `j` and `li` are in scope; `d` is not visible at that point. This is what the error message it telling you.

You can re-create the same issue very easily:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual a, dual b inner join dual c on a.dummy = c.dummy;
select 1 from dual a, dual b inner join dual c on a.dummy = c.dummy
                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "A"."DUMMY": invalid identifier
```

As opposed to:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual a, dual b inner join dual c on b.dummy = c.dummy;

         1
----------
         1
```

You already have the right way to do it in the accepted answer.